# For loop to change a specific cell in a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have a formula that shows which rows in a specific column meet a set of criteria. When the formula is executed and applied to all rows, I run a loop to check which rows returned a value as a text, and then copy-pastes this cells to another worksheet:

```
Sub loop1()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set r = Range(.Range("AF2"), .Range("AF2").End(xlDown))
        For Each c In r
            If WorksheetFunction.IsText(c) Then
                Range(.Cells(c.Row, "AF"), .Cells(c.Row, "AF")).Copy
            Else
                GoTo nextc
            End If
            With Worksheets("Sheet2")
            .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial  Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
nextc:

    Next c
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

What I want to do now is to run the formula for 631 different names, copy-paste every name as a headline and then run loop1. I cant figure out though how to make the for loop work **inside** the formula.

```
Sub loop2()

Dim i As Integer

  For i = 2 To 632


    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("AC2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-3]=""district1"",(IF(RC[2]=R2C33 ,(IF(RC[-18]>=1,0,(IF(RC[-16]>=1,0,IF(RC[-14]>=1,0,IF(RC[-12]>=1,0,IF(RC[-10]>=1,1,IF(RC[-8]>=1,1,IF(RC[-6]>=1,1,0))))))))),0)),0)"
    Range("AC2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AC2:AC20753")
    Range("AC2:AC20753").Select
    Range("AG2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Application.Run "'Customers.xlsb'!loop1"

  Next i


End Sub
```

The cells that need to be changed for every loop are, R2C33 to something like RiC33 (which doesn't work) and the "headline" Range("AG2").Select to something like Range("AGi").Select.

Anyone who could help?

Comment: It's the 2 in R2C33 I want to change, not the 33.

Comment: I think this question is a little more legitimate. In Loop2 the last operation is to copy AG2 from Sheet1 and paste it into sheet2 but there is no defined destination cell for the paste. Just Sheet2.

Comment: Had another look at your formula. It has a lot of conditions that end returning zero then three conditions that could return a one and if nothing matches then the return is a zero by default. Couldn't you shorten that formula to `=IF(OR(RC[-10]>=1, RC[-8]>=1, RC[-6]>=1), 1, 0)` since anything that does not match one of those criteria will become a zero one way or another?

Comment: I need the other cells to be 0 to be sure that it is a new customer.

Comment: @Jeeped from what I checked it can be shortened, but it still needs to check the 2 statements before its allowed to reach the final "check" and become 1. The way you made it now only checks if value from the last "check" is more then 1 and if yes output is 1.

Comment: @DragonSamu - Yes! that makes perfect sense as to why so many conditions had to fail before returning one was even considered. Thanks for finding the hole in my logical shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will do the trick:

```
Sub loop2()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 632
   Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AC2:AC20753").FormulaR1C1 = _
   "=IF(RC[-3]=""district1"",(IF(RC[2]=R" & i & "C33 ,(IF(RC[-18]>=1,0,(IF(RC[-16]>=1,0,IF(RC[-14]>=1,0,IF(RC[-12]>=1,0,IF(RC[-10]>=1,1,IF(RC[-8]>=1,1,IF(RC[-6]>=1,1,0))))))))),0)),0)"
   Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AG" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
   Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
   Application.Run "'Customers.xlsb'!loop1"
Next i

End Sub
```

In order to let `i` be used within your `String` formula you have to stop the `String` `"` use `& i &` and continue the `String` `"`.

I have also changed your code to prevent the use of .Select, which is a no no in VBA.
This way it fills in your `Formula` copy's and changes the Font without selecting anything or changing sheets.

As Jeep noted you do however need to change `Sheets(""Sheet2").Range("A1")` as I don't know which cell you want to paste into.

Comment: If `R2C33` is to be changed to `R" & i & "C33` where `i = 2` on row 2 then that can be written as `RC33` couldn't it?

Comment: From what I understand the OP wants to step through R2C33 and AG2, so R2C33 should stay the same. If you do RC33 its not absolute.

Comment: The OP clarified with 'It's the 2 in R2C33 I want to change, not the 33'. Also, could you take a quick look at my logic in the original question's comments. I may have found a way to shorten the formula consderably.

Comment: That is what I meant, therefor i did R & i & C33 as every step should change i. then the next step looks at AG3 in the next i step and copy from AG3

Comment: Thanks for looking. Appreciate it. The OP can decide.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sub procedure might be better like this.

```
Sub loop1()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set r = Range(.Range("AF2"), .Range("AF2").End(xlDown))
        For Each c In r
            If WorksheetFunction.IsText(c) Then
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
                    .Cells(c.Row, "AF").Value2
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Direct value transfer is preferred over a Copy, Paste Special, Values.

In the second sub procedure, you don't have to do anything but remove the 2 from `R2C33`; e.g. `RC33`. In xlR1C1 formula construction a lone R simply means the row that the formula is on and you are starting at row 2. You can also put all of the formulas in at once. Once they are in you can looop through the G2:G632 cells.

```
Sub loop2()
    Dim i As Integer

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("AC2:AC20753").FormulaR1C1 = _
          "=IF(OR(AND(RC[-3]=""district1"", RC[2]=R2C33, RC[-18]>=1), SUM(RC[-16], RC[-14], RC[-12])>=1), 0, IF(SUM(RC[-10], RC[-8], RC[-6])>=1, 1, 0))"

        For i = 2 To 632
            .Range("AG" & i).Copy _
                Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Somewhere
            Sheets("Sheet2").Somewhere.Font.Bold = True
            Application.Run "'Customers.xlsb'!loop1"
        Next i
  Next i

End Sub
```

I also tightened up your formula by grouping some of the conditions that would result in zero together with OR and AND functions.

The only thing remaining would be defining the `Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Somewhere` I left hanging.

Comment: There is still a minor flaw in your code as we where discussing before. he wants to check from AG* and with every i step go 1 down. So AG2 then AG3, AG4... so this step happens in the formula and in the copying. Thats also why (I think) he had the formula pasting within the For Next loop. This because the AG range is where he has a different name to validate/check

Comment: I think I'm just having a hard time believing that the OP wants to do 631 iterations with 20,752 cells. I'll have another look tomorrow.\

Comment: Made it work:
Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

and

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Font.Bold = True

Comment: DragonSamu is right. I got 631 branches and 20752 customers. I want to see how many new customers there are since 2012, and who the customers are, within the specific branches.
It works now, thanks so much for your help!